# How do i pass a javascript var into a function?

Tags: javascript, html

how do I pass play_ID into the the function toggleSound()?

```
onclick=\"javascript:var play_ID=$id;toggleSound();\"
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function toggleSound() {
        audioElem = document.getElementById(\"audio". $row["ID"]."\");
        if (audioElem.paused)
            audioElem.play();
        else
            audioElem.pause();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I want the elementById to = play_ID

Comment: What is play_ID, an input? Can you make a sample?

Comment: Does `play_ID` uniquely identify the element that's been clicked? If so you can call `toggleSound(this)` and declare the function as `toggleSound(audioElem)`

Comment: Why do you have backslash before some of the quotes? Is this part of a PHP `echo` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to pass the $Id variable into your function?

```
onclick=\"javascript:toggleSound($id);\"

<script type=\"text/javascript\">

<script type=\"text/javascript\">


 function toggleSound(inVar) {
    //inVar is equal to the variable you want to pass into the function.

        audioElem = document.getElementById(inVar);
        if (audioElem.paused)
            audioElem.play();
        else
            audioElem.pause();
    }
</script>
```